# Complex numbers, find all solutions of $Im(-z+i)=(z+i)^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I solve this equation: $Im(-z+i)=(z+i)^2$?

I am supposed to find all the complex solutions. The answer given is: $\pm \sqrt{2}-1 $

I have tried $Im(-z+i)=-y+1$  $\rightarrow$  $\sqrt{-y+1}=z+i$ but this gives no solution of the correct form.

Comment: Consider substituting $ z = x + yi $ where $ x, y \in \mathbb{R} $ and expanding everything.

Comment: For $z = \sqrt{2} - 1 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have something complex valued on the right side since $(z+i)^2 = z^2+2iz-1$, which will be complex in case of $z \in \mathbb{R}$. However, $\text{Im}(z)$ must be a real number (the real and imaginary part of a complex number are real numbers). Are you sure you've copied the right exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{Im}(-z + i) = \text{Im}(-z) + 1$$ and $$(z+i)^2 = z^2+2iz+i^2 = z^2+2iz-1$$
Suppose 
$$z = a +ib$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
We then have 
$$\text{Im}(-z) + 1 = -b + 1$$
Solving the initial equality gives us 
$$-b + 1 = (a + ib + i)^2$$
$$-b + 1 = (a+i(b+1))^2$$
$$-b + 1 = a^2 + 2i(b+1) + i^2(b+1)^2 $$
$$-b + 1 = a^2 + 2i(b+1) - (b+1)^2 $$
$$-b + 1 = (a^2-b^2-2b-1) + i(2b+2) $$
Now we compary imaginary and real part of both numbers in the equation. The left number has imaginary part $0$, so we must also have $2b+2 = 0$ on the right side, since that's where the imaginary part of that number is at.

Therefore
$$2b+2 = 0$$
$$b = -1$$
Now we solve for $a$ the same way with $b=-1$ known.

We get:
$$-b + 1 = (a^2-b^2-2b-1)$$
$$2 = a^2-(-1)^2+2-1$$
$$0 = a^2-2$$
$$2 = a^2$$
$$a = \pm \sqrt{2}$$
And therefore we have

$$z = a + ib$$
$$z = \pm \sqrt{2} - i$$

Answer (score 1):

With $z=x+iy$, the equation reads

$$\Im(-x-iy+i)=-y+1=\\
(z+i)^2=z^2+i2z-1=x^2-y^2-2y-1+i(2xy+2x).$$

By identifying the imaginary parts,

$$2xy+2x=0$$ i.e. $$x=0\text{ or }y=-1.$$

Then identifying the real parts,

- $x=0\implies -y^2-2y-1=-y+1$, which has no real solutions;
- $y=-1\implies x^2=2$, or $x=\pm\sqrt2$.

$$z=\pm\sqrt2-i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $z=a+ib$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. We have $\Im(-z+i)=-b+1$, and $(z+i)^2=(a^2-b^2-2b-1)+i(2a(b+1))$. So by indentifying imaginary and real part we have the following system : 
$$\begin{cases} 2a(b+1)=0 \\ a^2-b^2-2b-1=-b+1\end{cases} $$

The first equation leads to $2$ cases :

1. $a=0$
2. $b=-1$

If $a=0$ then the second equation is equivalent to $b^2+b+2=0$, after calculating the derteminant of this quadric, it does not have real solution, it is impossible since $b$ is supposed in $\mathbb{R}$.

So $b=-1$, and the second equation is equivalent to $a^2-2=0 \Rightarrow a=\sqrt{2}$ or $a=-\sqrt{2}$.

Finally $z=\pm \sqrt{2}-i$.